# Why is the Fokker-Planck equation only valid for the forward and backward velocities but not for the flux velocity?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, diffusion, stochastic-processes

[I noticed](https://books.google.de/books?id=fvocBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA124&ots=fl3NI9w3-d&dq=%22continuity%20equation%22%20%22osmotic%20velocity%22&hl=de&pg=PA124#v=onepage&q&f=false) that the Fokker-Planck equation is often only written for the forward velocity $\vec b$ and the backward velocity $\vec  b^*$:
\begin{align}
\partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec b \rho) &= D \nabla^2 \rho ,   \tag{1} \\
\partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec b^* \rho) &= - D \nabla^2 \rho . \tag{2}
\end{align}
By adding these two equations, we find the continuity equation for the flux velocity $\vec v \equiv \frac{1}{2} (\vec b + \vec b^* )$:
$$ \partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec v \rho) = 0 . \tag{3} $$
However, if we're dealing with a system undergoing advection and diffusion, [I would expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation#Derivation) that we describe it using the Fokker-Planck equation
$$ \partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec v \rho) =- D \nabla^2 \rho \tag{4} ,$$
which, in general, isn't correct here as we can see by comparing it to Eq. 3.

**Why is the Fokker-Planck equation (sometimes) only valid for the forward and backward velocity (Eq. 1, Eq. 2), but not for the flux velocity $\vec v$ (Eq. 4)? And why do we sometimes use the Fokker-Planck equation for $\vec v$ as given in Eq. 4 nevertheless?**

---

**A bit more background:**

Eq. 3 seems to suggest that we're dealing with a system that is solely governed by advection. This is not the case because we can also subtract Eq. 1 from Eq. 2 and then integrate to derive Fick's first law:
$$ u \rho = D \nabla \rho , $$
where $\vec u \equiv \frac{1}{2} (\vec b - \vec b^* )$ is the osmotic velocity. Hence, we can define a diffusion current $\vec J_d \equiv\vec  u \rho$ and an advection current $\vec J_a \equiv \vec v \rho$.

I would therefore expect that we can define a total current
$$  \vec J \equiv  \vec J_d + \vec J_a    $$
for which the continuity equation holds:
$$ \partial_t \rho + \nabla \vec J = 0 \, .$$ 
But this is not correct, since if we use the definition of the total current and Fick's first law, we find:
\begin{align}
\partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec J_d + \vec J_a ) &= 0 \\
\partial_t \rho + \nabla ( D \nabla \rho + \vec v \rho) \\
\partial_t \rho +  \nabla( \vec v \rho )=- D  \nabla^2 \rho \, .
\end{align}
This is exactly Eq. 4 which, in general, is not correct here, as we can see by looking at Eq. 3. In particular, we can inser Eq. 3 into Eq. 4 to find:
$$ 0=- D \nabla^2 \rho$$
In words, this means that there is no diffusion, which makes the equations we started with trivial and thus the whole exercise pointless.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand: are you talking about forward and backward Fokker-Planck equations?

Comment: @vadim yes Eq. 1 and Eq. 2 are the forward and backward Fokker-Planck equations

Comment: In a real Fokker-Planck equation $\rho$ is a function of two coordinates and (and, in principle, two times), so (1) and (2) cannot be so easily added, since they contain derivatives in respect to different variables. Also, FPE can always be written as a continuity equation with the appropriate definition of the currents.

Comment: @Vadim In the book I linked to in the first sentence, the two equations get added. (I've seen the same thing in many books and papers). So while it's certainly not always possible, it seems to be possible in some cases. Here I look at a system where it is possible.

Comment: I am not familiar with this particular context, so I probably can't help you. I think this is not what one normally calls forward/backward FPE. I can recommend Risken's book as the standard reference: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540615309