# How can we interpret a system in which the probability distribution obeys the forward and the backward Fokker-Planck equation simultaneously?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, diffusion, stochastic-processes, randomness

For a system involving randomness, there is no longer a unique derivative and hence no longer a unique definition of velocity. But for the forward (Ito) derivative, we can find a probability distribution $\rho$ that obeys the **forward Fokker-Planck equation**:
\begin{align}
\partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec b \rho) &= D \nabla^2 \rho ,   \tag{1} 
\end{align}
where $\vec b$ denotes the forward velocity.

Moreover, using the backward (anti-Ito) derivative, we can also find a probability distribution $\rho$ that obeys the **backward Fokker-Planck equation**:
\begin{align}
\partial_t \rho^* + \nabla (\vec b^* \rho^*) &= - D \nabla^2 \rho^* , \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\vec b^*$ denotes the backward velocity.

If we now assume that we're dealing with [a special system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543586/37286) for which $\rho^* =\rho$, we can add Eq. 1 and Eq. 2 to find that the average velocity $\vec v \equiv \frac{1}{2} (\vec b + \vec b^* )$ obeys an **ordinary continuity equation**:
$$ \partial_t \rho + \nabla (\vec v \rho) = 0 . \tag{3} $$
Hence, even though we're dealing with a system involving diffusion, the average velocity obeys and equation $\vec v $ that is typically only valid in systems without diffusion.

The key assumption in the derivation above is that $\rho^* =\rho$. In words this means that there is a unique distribution $\rho$ that obeys the forward *and* the backward Fokker-Planck equation at the same time. I'm trying to understand what this condition really means in physical terms.

**Formulated differently: does $\rho^* =\rho$ indicate that the process is time-symmetric (picture A below) or reversible (picture B below)?**

[image]